# Access flutter tests result in tearDownAll

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, flutterdriver

I need to access the tests result in `tearDownAll` callback. I want to check if any of the tests failed during the execution.

```
tearDownAll(() async {
  final success = // code here
});
```

I researched classes like `Invoker`, `Declarer`, `Engine`, `LiveTestController` and `test_core.dart` file. Seems like this is the code that does what I need.

```
var success = await runZoned(() => Invoker.guard(engine.run),
    zoneValues: {#test.declarer: _globalDeclarer});
if (success) return null;
print('');
unawaited(Future.error('Dummy exception to set exit code.'));
```

Unfortunately the `engine` is not accessible from outside. I've also not found API for checking the tests result in `test_core` library.

Is there a way to check if any of previous test has failed? I'd like use this inside a `tearDownAll()` or `test()` functions of a test group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a possible solution to my question, that requires some extra stuff in the test class.

Basically you have to check every single test result in `tearDown` and keep track of them, then in tearDownAll you can check if any of the test has failed.

```
import 'package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart';
import 'package:test_api/src/backend/state.dart' as test_api;

final failedTests = [];

tearDown(() {
  if (Invoker.current.liveTest.state.result == test_api.Result.error) {
    failedTests.add(Invoker.current.liveTest.individualName);
  }
});

tearDownAll(() {
  if (failedTests.isNotEmpty) {
    // do stuff
  }
});
```